# Need help to update sheet column with the values obtained via Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**So, I found a Google App Script (not created by me) to make file copies as follows:**

- I enter a file ID and destination folder ID on the sheet.
- The code creates a copy of the file in the given folder.

However, I need one additional functionality in the given app script to return the ID of the copied file back to the sheet.

Here is the sample sheet for you to assess: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b4LxpELHswC07KTNJeHYx7thxVRqvQ89WWq-kGFOxbU/edit?usp=sharing

Currently, the Copied File ID column remains blank after I run the code. I need it to be updated with the copied File IDs.

**Is this possible with some tweaking in the code?**

Thanks a ton already!

PS: I noticed there are some variables in the code related to copyfileID, but I couldn't find a way to return these to the sheet.

Here is the code I need to be tweaked:

```
       function test_fileCopier()
    {
      var t = new Date();
      var ids = false; // use "1;2;3" to copy certain task ids 
      var res = copyFiles_(ids);

  Logger.log(res);
  Logger.log('Time to run the script = ' + (new Date() -t) + ' ms.');
}


function copyFiles_(ids) {
  getSettings_();
  var d = CCC_.STR_DELIMEER1;
  var all_ids = CCC_.STR_TASKID_FILECOPIER.split(d);
  var all_fileIds = CCC_.STR_FILE_ID_FILECOPIER.split(d);
  var all_folderIds = CCC_.STR_FOLDER_TO_ID_FILECOPIER.split(d);
  var all_prefix = CCC_.STR_NAME_PREFIX_FILECOPIER.split(d);
  var all_postfix = CCC_.STR_NAME_POSTFIX_FILECOPIER.split(d);
  
  
  if (!ids) { ids = all_ids; }
  else { ids = ids.split(d); }
  
  var res = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < all_ids.length; i++)
  {
    var id = all_ids[i];
    if (ids.indexOf(id) > -1)
    {
      var fileCopier = 
          {
            fileId: all_fileIds[i],
            folderId: all_folderIds[i],
            prefix: all_prefix[i],
            postfix: all_postfix[i]
          }
      var subRes = copyFile_(fileCopier);
      res.push(subRes);
    }    
  }
  return res;
}


function copyFile_(fileCopier)
{
  var fileId = fileCopier.fileId, 
      folderId = fileCopier.folderId, 
      prefix = fileCopier.prefix, 
      postfix = fileCopier.postfix;
  
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  if (!file) { return -1; } // no file
  var type = file.getMimeType();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  if (!folder) { return -2; } // no folder
  var name = file.getName();
  
  switch (type) {
    case MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS:
      // copy the form too
      var copy = file.makeCopy(folder);
      var copyId = copy.getId();
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(copyId); // get file of a copy
      if (!ss) { return -3; } // no ss??
      var formUrl = ss.getFormUrl();
      if (formUrl)
      {
        var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl);
        var formId = form.getId();
        var formFile = DriveApp.getFileById(formId);
        // get folders from form copy
        var fileParents = formFile.getParents();
        // add to folder
        folder.addFile(formFile); 
        // remove old copies        
        while ( fileParents.hasNext() ) {
          var folderFrom = fileParents.next();
          folderFrom.removeFile(formFile);
        }
        // rename file copy
        formFile.setName(prefix + name + postfix);        
      }
      break;
    case MimeType.GOOGLE_FORMS:
      // do not copy the form
      return -4; // userforms are copied automatically with linked spreadsheet
    default:
      // copy as usual
      var copy = file.makeCopy(folder);
  }
  // rename copy
  copy.setName(prefix + name + postfix);
  return 0; 
  
}
```

Comment: Can you add your current script in your question?

Comment: Please check now @Tanaike

Answer (score 1):

### You need to return the `id` of the new file from `function copyFile_(fileCopier)` to `function copyFiles_(ids)`

Currently, the former function only returns numbers.

You can modify it as following:

```js
function copyFile_(fileCopier)
{
  var fileId = fileCopier.fileId, 
      folderId = fileCopier.folderId, 
      prefix = fileCopier.prefix, 
      postfix = fileCopier.postfix;
  
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  if (!file) { return -1; } // no file
  var type = file.getMimeType();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  if (!folder) { return -2; } // no folder
  var name = file.getName();
  
  switch (type) {
    case MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS:
      // copy the form too
      var copy = file.makeCopy(folder);
      var copyId = copy.getId();
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(copyId); // get file of a copy
      if (!ss) { return -3; } // no ss??
      var formUrl = ss.getFormUrl();
      if (formUrl)
      {
       ...
        }
        // rename file copy
        formFile.setName(prefix + name + postfix);        
      }
      return copyId;
    case MimeType.GOOGLE_FORMS:
      // do not copy the form
      return -4; // userforms are copied automatically with linked spreadsheet
    default:
      // copy as usual
      var copy = file.makeCopy(folder);
  }
  // rename copy
  copy.setName(prefix + name + postfix);
  return copy.getId();  
}
```

Now, to set the `id` back into the spreadsheet, you can to use the function [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) in `function copyFiles_(ids)` .

For example:

```js
...
var subRes = copyFile_(fileCopier);
sheet.getRange("F" + (i+2)).setValue(subRes);
...
```

Comment: The aim is to return the copied file name to sheet column F. That column is still empty when I run the code.

Comment: So you want to return the name, not the ID? As for the column being empty - you obviously need to implement some funcitonality to set the value into the sheet (pushing it into an array is not enough). I updated my code to show you how.